# How can I query or check for a list of tables using liquid clustering in Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure-databricks

Currently, I need to check for which tables using liquid clustering in all the schemas for every catalog and I also need to check for the legacy hive_metastore catalog as well. It seems like microsoft documentation does not store this information in the Unity Catalog's system tables.

How can I query or check for a list of tables using liquid clustering in Azure Databricks ?

This is the edition made after the answer provided by JayashankarGS. For
non-delta external tables which also implementing liquid clustering, the `DESCRIBE DETAIL` would returns the FileAlreadyExistsException error. Therefore, the solution below would work for my case:

```
%python

tables = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM system.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE table_schema != 'information_schema'").select("table_catalog","table_schema","table_name").rdd.map(lambda x:(x.table_catalog,x.table_schema,x.table_name)).collect()
clustered_tables = []

for i in tables:

    df_object_type = spark.sql(f"SHOW TBLPROPERTIES {i[0]}.{i[1]}.{i[2]}")
    df_cluster_columns = df_object_type.where(df_object_type.key == 'delta.liquid.clusteringColumns')
    cluster_col = df_cluster_columns.rdd.map(lambda x: x["value"]).collect()

    # cluster_col = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE DETAIL {i[0]}.{i[1]}.{i[2]}").select("clusteringColumns").rdd.map(lambda x:x.clusteringColumns).collect()[0]

    if len(cluster_col) != 0:
        clustered_tables.append(f"{i[0]}.{i[1]}.{i[2]}")

print(clustered_tables)
```

Again, thank you JayashankarGS. Your solution provided me the correct approach to resolve the issue.

Kind regards,

Ken Masters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below to obtain tables with liquid clustering:

```py
tables = spark.sql("show tables in default").select("database","tableName").rdd.map(lambda x:(x.database,x.tableName)).collect()
clustered_tables = []

for i in tables:
    cluster_col = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE DETAIL {i[0]}.{i[1]}").select("clusteringColumns").rdd.map(lambda x:x.clusteringColumns).collect()[0]
    if len(cluster_col) != 0:
        clustered_tables.append(i)
```

Here, I am getting the tables in the database and looping through them to get details of `clusteringColumns`. If any columns are configured, then I append the table.

Output:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: the DESCRIBE DETAIL seems not to work for non-delta tables. I have edited my question with your proposed solution.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for giving generic way.